# Message: Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

First i read other posts of users with similiar problems, but couldnt come along where my mistake is. I wanted to start a test with RSpec on the following file:

dashboard_view_spec.rb:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.feature "Dashboard", type: :feature do 
before(:each) do
@current_user = User.create!(email: "xyz@xyz.com", password: "xyz123")
sign_in_with(@current_user.email,@current_user.password)
end

#NAV BAR RSPEC TEST
scenario 'Home bar nav link present' do
visit "/"
expect(page).to have_text('Home')
end

scenario 'How it work nav bar link present' do
visit "/"
expect(page).to have_text('How it work')
end

scenario 'Support nav bar link present' do
visit "/"
expect(page).to have_text('Support')
end

end
```

On rails_helper.rb on the top:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'

require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
# Prevent database truncation if the environment is production
abort("The Rails environment is running in production mode!") if   Rails.env.production?

require 'rake'
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'shoulda/matchers'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'rspec/retry'
require 'devise'
```

Error message:

```
Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

NoMethodError:
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
# ./config/initializers/devise.rb:258:in `block in <top (required)>'
# ./config/initializers/devise.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
# ./config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `require'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/views/dashboard_view_spec.rb:1:in `require'
# ./spec/views/dashboard_view_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
No examples found.

Randomized with seed 14549
```

Then the command i used on the terminal

```
 bundle exec rspec spec/views/dashboard_view_spec.rb
```

After watching the documentation of testing with Devise i changed the code in               *dashboard_view_spec.rb* and used to **sign_in** as a **user** and got the same error message.

Line 258 of devise.rb

```
 config.omniauth :facebook, Rails.application.secrets.facebook[:key],  Rails.application.secrets.facebook[:secret], scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email, name'
```

In the gemfile

```
group :development, :test do
# Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger     console
 gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
 # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
 gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
 gem 'selenium-webdriver'
 gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.8'
 gem 'factory_girl_rails'
 gem 'faker'
 gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

and

```
group :development do
# Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %>    anywhere in the code.
gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the  background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring'
gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
```

Comment: Could you add the complete stack trace and the command executed?

Comment: I added the command. There was no stack trace on the output of the error. I snapshot the error message of the terminal.

Comment: I changed it. Hope its better now. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You still haven't posted what's in `config/initializers/devise.rb:258`. The error message is really straightforward: something on line 258 is attempting to perform `[]` on an object that it expects to be an `Array` but is actually `nil`. Find that object, find out why it's `nil` instead of an `Array`, then fix it. Chances are it's referencing something that is defined in your `development` environment but not your `test` environment, which is why you get this error in the `test` environment. Changes to the rest of your test don't matter -- it's failing on _line 1_, before your spec runs.

Comment: I added the line in the starting post.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you're missing a variable that your devise initializer expects to find, but only missing it in the `test` environment. (not the `development` environment)

The stack trace that you provided and line 258 from `config/initializers/devise.rb` are all that are needed. First, let's look at the stack trace:

```
NoMethodError:
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
# ./config/initializers/devise.rb:258:in `block in <top (required)>'
# ./config/initializers/devise.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
# ./config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `require'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/views/dashboard_view_spec.rb:1:in `require'
# ./spec/views/dashboard_view_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Starting from the bottom up, we can see that the first line of your spec is what's causing the issue. If you follow the stack you'll see that it ends up in `config/initializers/devise.rb:258` and is complaining that something making a `[]` method call isn't getting the expected object type in return, and is instead getting `nil` in return.

Looking at line 258 you find:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, Rails.application.secrets.facebook[:key],  Rails.application.secrets.facebook[:secret], scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email, name'
```

So you can see that there are two times that `[]` is called:

```
Rails.application.secrets.facebook[:key]
Rails.application.secrets.facebook[:secret]
```

What is expected is that calling `Rails.application.secrets.facebook` will return an `Enumerable` object (like an array or a hash) but instead it is returning `nil`, and when it attempts to run `nil[:key]` or `nil[:secret]` it raises an exception because `NilClass` is not an `Enumerable` and does not have a `[]` method. You can test this yourself in the `rails console`:

```
nil[:secret]
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

The solution is to ensure that calling `Rails.application.secrets.facebook` returns the expected object type. The short answer is to edit `config/secrets.yml` to ensure that the values you require for the `test` environment are present.

I haven't worked with devise in a long time, but I assume that you can safely use the same values that you're using for the `development` environment for the `test` environment. You can read more about [`secrets()`](https://apidock.com/rails/Rails/Application/secrets) elsewhere, but the basic template for `config/secrets.yml` is as follows:

```
environment:
  key: value
```

For example:

```
test:
  my_secret_key: my_secret_value
```

It should be fairly straightforward to copy and paste the missing `facebook` secrets into the `test` environment. After making the change you can verify it worked:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=test rails console
Rails.application.secrets.facebook[:key]
=> <your key here>
```

If that worked, then run your spec with `rspec` and it should successfully get past line 1. (assuming there are no other bugs or missing secrets)

Comment: I appreciate that the first line tells us all we need to know, especially where the missing file isn't an initialiser (in my case it was a spec helper)

Answer (score 3):

I had very similar errors. Here's how I solved

Run `rspec --backtrace`

This could produce a lot of console output. Scroll right to the top, and start reading from the top. It will tell you the file your problem started in, and the line it happened on. Go to that file (and that line), and figure out what's missing.

In my case, it was actually a missing variable in `credentials.yml`, but cases will vary. Like in the excellent answer by @anothermh, it's basically telling you something is missing, so you have to figure out what's missing and make sure you provide it.

Answer (score 2):

Just got the same error, but when I ran `bundle exec rake spec` instead of `bundle exec rspec` it worked.