# RSpec - An error occurred while loading - Did you mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I want to start with TDD, but I am having this error, I am working with rvm - ruby 3.0.0 and rails 6.1.1

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/models/user_spec.rb. - Did you mean?
                rspec ./spec/spec_helper.rb

Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)

LoadError:
  cannot load such file -- rexml/document
 /home/manci/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:34:in `require'
 /home/manci/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
 /home/manci/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
 /home/manci/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.142.7/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox.rb:22:in `<main>'
 /home/manci/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 6):

As [Jon Rowe](https://github.com/JonRowe), member of RSpec, pointed out here (https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/2441#issuecomment-756621403), if you're using Ruby 3.0.0 you must install `rexml`.

This gem was removed from the standard gemset in Ruby 3.0.0 and is needed by `rails-controller-tests`

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/2441

For posterity, the latest versions (I think) of ruby and rails which you can (currently) use with rspec are:

ruby 2.7.2
rails 6.0.3

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar (but different) error message, and the cause was different.

I solved by running `rspec --backtrace` and scrolling to the top of the output and read the first line onwards, its should narrow the scope of the problem significantly. (In my case I was missing some creds for my test environment, but cases will vary). More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66419271/5783745).